# Redirect to home page after saml authentification (login)

Tags: go, saml, gorilla, mux

I'm trying to integrate saml using [crewjam](https://github.com/crewjam/saml) library with an open-source app in go.

After authentication test using samltest.id, I want to be redirected to the home page.

I have tried several ways, but nothing works well, i'm using gorilla/mux router:

```go
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s := samlsp.SessionFromContext(r.Context())
    if s == nil {
        return
    }
    sa, ok := s.(samlsp.SessionWithAttributes)
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Token contents, %+v!", sa.GetAttributes())

    w.Header().Add("Location", "http://localhost:8080/")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
}
```

I have also tested :

```go
http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080/", http.StatusFound)
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does your code reach the` http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080/", http.StatusFound)`
portion? 
the redirection should work, try checking if the ok value is not nil (you might have an error).

Comment: yes, I have an ok because I have the content of fmt.Fprintf which is displayed well on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calling `w.Write` or writing into it using `Fmt.Fprintf` requires **HTTP status code** to be set before, otherwise it sets default `StatusOK`**

[Server.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/net/http/server.go;l=144)

> // If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write
> // will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK).

Setting the status code multiple times throws superfluous log.

Therefore, Your code is setting the HTTP status code to **200** `(http.StatusOk)`,  so the redirect after that is simply impossible.

## Solution:

```
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s := samlsp.SessionFromContext(r.Context())
    if s == nil {
        return
    }
    sa, ok := s.(samlsp.SessionWithAttributes)
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    // this line is removed 
    // fmt.Fprintf(w, "Token contents, %+v!", sa.GetAttributes())

    w.Header().Add("Location", "http://localhost:8080/")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
    // Or Simply 
    // http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080/", http.StatusFound)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to send your headers **before** writing content.
And optionally use a relative Location

```
w.Header().Add("Location", "/")
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)

fmt.Fprintf(w, "Token contents, %+v!", sa.GetAttributes())
```